# Example where Banach fix point theorem isn't valid

Tags: metric-spaces, banach-fixed-point

Can someone give me an example of a complete metric space that doesn't have fix point theorem? (Counterexample of fixed point Banach theorem).

Comment: In order to "find a counterexample" you need to relax one of the hypotheses of the theorem. Which hypothesis do you want to relax?

Comment: the empty space

Comment: @User8128 I want to find example where f:X->X and d(f(x),f(y))<d(x,y)

Comment: @justhope21: You are not the original poster here, are you?  In any case the issue is what conditions on $X$, the metric space, can be relaxed.

Answer (score 4):

Classic example of function with $d(f(x),f(y))<d(x,y)$ and without fixed point in a complete space
$$f(x) = x + \frac1x,\qquad X = [1,\infty).$$